# how to properly get a blob(MAX) image from SQL db

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, blob, sqlsrv

When i try to get a image as blob i get this response: 
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.

my code is as following, 
The GET query

```
function GET_shopimages($shopid){
    $currentUserName = Auth::user()->name;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM srms_dam.dbo.pictures WHERE srms_dam.dbo.pictures.shopid = (?) ";
    $parameters = array((int) $shopid);
    return executeImageObjectQuery($query, $parameters);
}
```

the executeImageObjectQuery:

```
 function executeImageObjectQuery($inputQuery, $stagingParameters){
        $conn = buildConnection();
        if( $conn ) {
            $query = $inputQuery;
            $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $stagingParameters);
            $detailresult  = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result); echo '<img 
            src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['picture'] ).'"/>';
            sqlsrv_close ($conn);
            return $detailresult;
      } else {
         return response('Cannot build database connection', 503);
    }
}
```

I already looked at the different questions surrounding blob but could not find an answer, any help would be greatly appreciated. 
the Query worked in the database itself.
$detailresult = $result here.

(if i need to insert my routing code please let me know)

---

Since this took to long to figure out i decided to just upload the picture path in the db and go from there. Question still remains though because i'm sure i am not the only one having this issue

Comment: You should evaluate what is returned from `sqlsrv_query`. You get boolean result from probably that method and boolean for that method means you get `FALSE` response. Use `sqlsrv_errors` to investigate errors.

Comment: _$detailresult = $result here_ : No, it doesn't seem so. `$result` is a statement resource and `$detailresult` is an array, null or false value.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a typo error:

```
$result['picture']
```

You fetch results into `$detailresult` and you should use it:

```
$detailresult['picture']
```

Still, you may get some errors from your sql query, therefore I would use [`sqlsrv_errors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-errors).

Comment: yeah i have a piece of code thas makes $result equal to $detailresult, sorry for not showing that.

Comment: @TerranGaming Can you please update your question regarding with the information you provide?